# Quicksort partitioning

Tags: java, quicksort

I have the following array:

```
int[] arr = { 19, 4, 2, 3, 9, 2, 10, 2, 7, 12, 5, 16, 8, 3, 11, 14, 0, 5 };
```

And now I use quicksort's partitioning to partition the array with pivot element 7:

```
    public static void partition(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    int pivot = arr[low + (high - low) / 2];
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    while (i <= j) {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        while (arr[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        while (arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        // As we are done we can increase i and j
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(arr, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused with the outcome:

```
5 4 2 3 0 2 3 2 5 12 7 16 8 10 11 14 9 19
```

I thought that every element <= pivot (7) must be to the left and every element > than pivot element must be on the right. But why is 12 left to 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

This implementation cannot guarantee what you would expect. All it does is the following (provided that you change to `arr[i] <= pivot`, as Achintya Jha suggested, otherwise it can't even guarantee that):

For every pair of values `a, b` with `a <= pivot < b`, it is guaranteed that `a` will be left of `b` in the end. However, you don't guarantee *anything* about the exact position of `pivot` in the final array (only that it's left of all values that are larger).

Answer (score 0):

A `partition` function in C++ looks like this:

```
  while (first!=last) {
    while (pred(*first)) {
      ++first;
      if (first==last) return first;
    }
    do {
      --last;
      if (first==last) return first;
    } while (!pred(*last));
    swap (*first,*last);
    ++first;
  }
  return first;
```

`First` and `last` are iterators that point to elements in the array, analogous to your `i` and `j` variables. `pred` is short for predicate, which could be `i <= 7` for example. Essentially this function returns the midpoint, so in C++ code, you would get all elements to the left of the midpoint by iterating up to it, and all elements to the right by iterating from it to the end. To make it less confusing:

i should be the first element, j should be the last element.

// get midpoint first

...

```
// Note. <= is the opposite of >
// Which logically is the same as
// pred is the opposite of !pred
  while (i != j) {
    while (i <= midpoint) {
      ++i;
      if (i == j) return i;
    }
    do {
      --j;
      if (i == j) return i;
    } while (i > midpoint);
    swap (i, j);
    ++i;
  }
  return i;

...

for (int i = 0; i < get_midpoint(...); i++)
for (int i = get_midpoint; i < end_of_array; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for the quicksort method

```
package com.Ramesh;

public class QuickSort {

public void sort(int[] a,int left,int right){
    if(left<right)
    {
        int partition=getPartition(a, left, right);
        sort(a,left,partition-1);
        sort(a,partition+1,right);
    }
}
public int getPartition(int[] a,int l,int r)
{
    int pivot=a[l];
    int left=l;
    int right=r;
    while(left<right)
    {
        while(a[left]<pivot){
            left++;
        }

        while(a[right]>pivot){
            right--;
        }

        if(left<right){
            int temp=a[left];
            a[left]=a[right];
            a[right]=temp;
        }

    }
    return right;
}

}
```

2.Create another class to invoke the sort method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Execute {

    private int[] a;
    private int len;

    public int[] getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getLen() {
        return len;
    }

    public void setLen(int len) {
        this.len = len;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Execute ex=new Execute();
        ex.takeInput();
        QuickSort q=new QuickSort();
        q.sort(ex.getA(),0,ex.getLen()-1);
        System.out.println("Printing the the Sorted Object");
        System.out.println(ex);
        }

    public void takeInput()
    {
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the no of element to be sorted");
        len=s1.nextInt();
        a=new int[len];
        System.out.println("Pls enter the elements");
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            a[i]=s1.nextInt();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer("");
        for(int i=0;i<this.len;i++){
            s.append(this.a[i]+"\n");
        }
        return s.toString();

    }

}
```